# Need to let users login with multiple credentials same as login with other account functionality in Gmail services- Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, session, eloquent, guard

I want to let my users to login with different `credentials` in the same browser window, which is using the single `users` table. If tables were different then I will surely do that with `guards`, but the problem is I have to manage the user logins through single table.

Please help me how to manage multiple sessions in the same browser window, as when I login with other account in a new tab the first one goes logout.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I wanted to do was to maintain `multiple session` for a user, so he can log in with his other email-ids inside the same browser window in different tabs.
Here we go, how we can manage that and how `Gmail` is managing it.

- At first you have to manage that, the `user` want to login with his other account or switch accounts. So you can show him the login page by appending any notation in `url` that shows he want to switch accounts.

If your original `login` URL is `http://www.examle.com/login`
then for multiple login, you can give him URL like `http://www.examle.com/u/1/login` (you can increase the number after `u/` part as many times you want to switch accounts)

- Then go to your `config/sessions.php` and edit your `cookie` part as follows

```
<?php

$user_type = ( ( !empty(request()) && (int)request()->segment(2) ) > 0 ? '_'. request()->segment(2) : '');

return [
    //.....rest of array

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'. $user_type //This user_type generate various session keys for your multiple login according to generated URL
    ),
];
```

- Then you have to change your all URL's as `dynamic` so that it can execute for both your normal route(`without '/u/number/url' part`) and with the `/u/number/url` part.
- Define the following variable at the top of your `web.php`

```
/**
 * Setting a variable to check if the user is logging in with first or multiple sessions
 */
$user_login = ( (int)request()->segment(2) > 0 ? 'u/'. request()->segment(2) : '' );

/**
 * User attempting to login with other accounts
 */
Route::post($user_login. '/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');

/**
 * Get dashboard for filling the registeration forms
 * Your entire app URL will now go like this, whether you can use it with user number or without it. It will go smoothly
 */
Route::get($user_login. '/dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'FormController@getDashboard']);

/**
 * User attempting to login with other accounts
 */
Route::post($user_login. '/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

- This works great. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: HI,
do we have to change all other routes as well. I have tried to implement this but after login I got same user on different tabs/panels.
please let me know what I need to do to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah due to multiple session in same browser window all routes gets affected. Use $user_login variable and append it in your all routes. Then if you have single login then all routes will be as normal as it should be, but when there is multiple session then it will get appended by itself nothing to worry about.

Comment: @ShahrukhAnwar Hi, i have tried this but give me error `Target class [request] does not exist.` when set on session config. iam using laravel 9

Comment: @Syaifudin Zuhri, try something else to get the request object, not sure if Laravel 9 makes any issue, but if you can find a workaround to get the request object, everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new guard in admin auth with same model.

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'front' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ],
```

In the controller:

```
if ($this->guard()->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'active' => 1])) {
            dd(' i am logged in');
        }
    }


protected function guard()
{
    return auth()->guard('front');
}
```

Comment: What about when I want to login in again in a third tab?. This is not what I asked, I know you can do that with `guards`, but in this case you have to manage things with multiple sessions for multiple users. 
Thanks BTW.